DropDownMenu in Flutter can detect click over arrow icon?
I am using the searching mode in DropDowmMenu.
So we can filter the itens by writing some value.
I need to auto clean what we wrote when we click in the arrow to open the list itens.
Is it possible? I tried inkweel but nop, always only the event in the dropdown is fired. Ontap from inkwell never is fired.
But its not a good way even if was worked, because the idea is fire only when we open the item list. And it happens when we click in the arrow in the right side.
Thank you!
Container(
    //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
    ),
    width: double.infinity,
        child:
            DropdownMenu<Models>(
            label: Text(translation(context)!.dropModel),
            dropdownMenuEntries: dropdownModelsItems,
            requestFocusOnTap: true,
            onSelected: dropDownModelsCallBack,
            enableSearch: true,
            controller: modelController,
            enableFilter: true,
            menuStyle: const MenuStyle(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              maximumSize:
              MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size.fromHeight(400)),
            ),
            expandedInsets: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
              isDense: true,

              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 300, maxWidth: 700, maxHeight: 40),

              fillColor: Colors.red,
              //filled: true,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
            ),
        ),
),


It does not directly provide an event for when the arrow icon is clicked. However, you can achieve this functionality with PopupMenuButton.

I already tried this widget and the problem is that doenst have the option to search content inside.  Do you think that is possible we overlay and transparent button over the arrow and fired both event with one clck?

Have you tried the DropdownMenu's searchCallback method? Try calling this method for an arrow trigger.
